# Socket.Io session does not disconnect on mobile devices

Tags: socket.io, webrtc

I have programmed a video chat in AngularJS. It uses WebRTC and socket.io.

Two users "see" each other because they are connected to the same socket.io room.
This all works fine.

However, what happens when a mobile phone goes idle or locked out, web browser does not detect this and the session does not die.

My expectation is that when a user lock / unlock his phone or phone goes idle I should be able to get an event which I can further use.

Comment: Same as in my chat app,if mobile user disconnects he is still in sidebar as other users and i cant solve that.